# How to get document names inside a folder in sharepoint document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, file, sharepoint-library

I have a document Library in which there are a number of different folders. Each folder contain different documents. I need to fetch the name of all the documents in a particular folder.
So far I have created the endpoint URL that is:

```
https:// Sharepointsite/sites/DeveloperSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('folderrelativeUrl')/Files
```

This URL gives me null result even if files are present in the folder. When I remove the folder name from URL and put `folderRelativeUrl` till document Library, I got the result of all the document and files in that library.

I am using c# REST API in visual studio and I am not sure as how to get the name of the documents.

Can anyone provide some information regarding this?

It will be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below endpoints and see which suits best for your use:

1) Using `FileLeafRef` property:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<library title>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef
```

2) Using `File/Name` property:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<library title>')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File
```

3) Using `Folder/Files` property:

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<folderrelativeUrl>')/files?$select=Name
```

**Additional Reference**:

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest).

Comment: Hi Ganesh i need list of all documents in a particular folder. I have tried these properties but no success. The first two will provide a particular file and the later one is giving me null response.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I got the documents list, passing incorrect library name.

Comment: Could you please help as, how to save these document names using Rest API

Comment: Where do you want to save this names?

Comment: We have a website, hitting this endpoint the list of document should be shown on that portal, only name I need.

Comment: This is something specific to your web site. I am not sure how you are going to show on your website.

Comment: How we can save name of documents in in any generic list or Dictionary using Rest, can you suggest? Cause I am able to fetch the name, just not sure where to save them.

Comment: You need to iterate on the results array you are getting from REST url and then you access the Name/FileLeafRef(which is suitable for you) and then push it in array/list/dictionary.

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code, I'm new to REST api, so I'm not understanding as to how to do it.

Comment: Can you add the function/code you are using to get the file name to your original question or by creating new question? that will be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: `const string RESTURL = "{0}_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{1}')/Files?&select=Name"; 
// {1} = update location where document have to be uplaoded

                string rESTUrl = string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl, folderServerRelativeUrl);

StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("");

                        //Perform post

                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(rESTUrl, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        //Ensure 200 (Ok)
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`

Comment: What are you getting in `response` variable? can you please ask new question with all details (your code snippet and what values you are getting in response variable)? Refer this question in your new question. code written in comment is not easy to understand.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I have done it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, welcome.